# how to change the font color of a textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I created a function that is activated when all the search textbox included in GroupBox3 and goes to set the text color to white, the problem is that the text color is not set. How is this possible?

```
Dim name As String
    For i = 0 To Me.GroupBox3.Controls.Count - 1
        name = Me.GroupBox3.Controls(i).GetType().ToString()
        If name.Contains("TextBox") Then
            Me.GroupBox3.Controls(i).ForeColor = Color.White 
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Hmmm... I just tried this and it seems to work for me :-/   Are the  text boxes and/or the group box set to .Enabled = False?  Otherwise I can't think of a reason this wouldn't work.

Comment: is set to enabled = false

Comment: Is this part of a long-running process, where perhaps the screen doesn't get a chance to redraw until after the process has finished?

Comment: I didn't understand anything of what you said. Anyway I just want to know how to solve the problem.

Comment: If the textboxes are Enabled = False, the ForeColor won't change the way you're specifying.  Are you able to change the textboxes Enabled = True?  Can the user enter values in them?

Comment: If you DO need to protect the text boxes from modification, you might want to:  (1) set textboxes Enabled = True   (2) set textboxes ReadOnly = True.  That allows you to change the ForeColor and still protect the textboxes from entry.